# Updating restygwt from 1.3 to 2.2.3 breaks existing code

Tags: java, gwt

I updated restygwt dependency from version 1.3 to 2.2.3 in my web-application. This upgrade is breaking my existing code. I am getting an error: `[ERROR] Neither public argument id nor public getter getId found!` while compiling GWT Repository interface.
I found the cause of an error is `@Attribute` annotation in the following function of repository.

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
void update(@PathParam("id") @Attribute("id") T object, MethodCallback<Void> callback);
```

The `object` is an object of generic type T which is a DTO extended from other super-class DTO.
Superclass DTO has public method `getId()` and private attribute `id`. I don't know why compiler gives an error even when a public method exists in superclass DTO.

NOTE:

1. The same code was working with restygwt version 1.3.
2. When I added `@Override public getId()` method in sub-class DTO then the error goes away. (Why so? superclass has already had the same method, then why the compiler couldn't able to find it?)
3. Changing `@Attribute("id")` to `@Attribute("getId()")` doesn't work either.

===================================================================

```
    public abstract class AbstractDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
    }
```

is super-class DTO and data (i.e.  `object` argument of `update()` function) is class extended by super-class.

Comment: can you provide the data and super class?

Comment: super-class and data(actual `dto` in `update()` function) is added in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `JsonSubTypes`-annotation on your super class.

Add something like this to your super class:

```
@JsonSubTypes({ 
     @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = YourSubClass01.class, name = "YourSubClass01"),
     @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = YourSubClass02.class, name = "YourSubClass02")
})
```

And add this annotation to each sub class:

```
@JsonTypeName("YourSubClass01")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
              include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY)
public class YourSubClass01 { ... }
```

More informations here: https://resty-gwt.github.io/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: This gives me error while compiling `Failed to read module XML file sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@1be2e122`